# Qt: changing user variable indicates the change of control's state

Tags: c++, qt, data-binding

Is it possible to simply indicate the change of some Qt control's property by changing value of user defined variable (perform an action on changing value). Eg. I declared `int a` which is frequently used by multiple functions. Now I need to construct a relation: `if ( a == 0 ) then` my control is inactive `else` my control is active. (I was inspired by C# data bindings.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt, controls are enabled/disabled with QWidget::setEnabled.  What you'll need to do is create a subclass from which all your gui windows are derived, in which you define a function that sets this variable and calls setEnabled.  Like this:

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
   ...
   MySetEnabled(bool b)
   {
      a = b;
      setEnabled(b);
   }

   int a;
};
```

Comment: But then I have to rewrite all the functions that use `a` variable, and that's the part I'd like to avoid. I'm rather looking for some relation like: changing state of `a` results in emiting SIGNAL that I can connect to setEnabled. Is such thing possible? I don't mean that I must use signals in here.

Comment: @Zacateras simply put no, there is no way to 'monitor' a variable in c++ like that.

Answer (score 0):

[Signals/Slots](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/signalsandslots.html)

In your accessor methods emit a signal that connect to actions you like to happen.

Comment: If I could emit signal on state change of `a` variable I would be satisfied.

Comment: @Zacateras, you can with properties, see the notify signal: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/properties.html